# posts.map is not a funtion in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

It was working yesterday. I don't know what happen even it try to checkout old commits still this error is showing.

redux state

```js
const initialState = {
  mode: "light",
  user: null,
  token: null,
  posts: [],
};
```

error area

```js
const PostsWidget = ({ userId, isProfile = false }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
  const token = useSelector((state) => state.token);

  return (
    <>
      {posts.map(
        ({
          _id,
          userId,
          firstName,
          lastName,
          description,
          location,
          picturePath,
          userPicturePath,
          likes,
          comments,
        }) => (
```

Comment: If you've rolled back the code and the error is still occurring, you should look at any saved data that might be persisting between builds (e.g. data in local storage)

Comment: try to run after updating the code like following...  `posts.map` => `posts?.map`

Comment: maybe the error is that the `posts` are not an array means, it will be an empty array or if you have any data then you must reload your page so it browser remove the data. You need to persist your data

Comment: Whatever `posts` is in the code it is an object that doesn't have a `map` method that is a function to be called. Check what you have stored in and selected from state. Can you [edit] to include a ***complete*** [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with along with the exact steps to reproduce the issue?